# I'm trying to mark out 4 points on my ImageView using 4 dots. When I move one of the views, the other one moves automatically

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to mark out 4 points on my ImageView using 4 dots. When I move one of the views, the other one moves automatically. The reason is because I'm mapping them to each other. But if I don't map them to each other, they just overlap which looks really ugly(not that it looks any less now). Please help me separate these 4 layouts. I've been banging my head against the wall for a while now. I've attached by XML and JAVA code below.

activity_mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/test"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTopLeftMarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Top Left"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/tag" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTopRightMarker"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layoutTopLeftMarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Top Right"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tag" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottomLeftMarker"
        android:layout_below="@id/layoutTopLeftMarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bottom Left"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tag"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottomRightMarker"
        android:layout_below="@id/layoutTopRightMarker"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layoutBottomLeftMarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bottom Right"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tag" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.pointmapperpoc;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imgMapper;
    private LinearLayout layoutTopLeftMarker,layoutTopRightMarker,layoutBottomLeftMarker,layoutBottomRightMarker;
    private int _yDeltaTopRight;
    private int _xDeltaTopRight;
    private int _yDeltaTopLeft;
    private int _xDeltaTopLeft;
    private int _xDeltaBottomLeft;
    private int _yDeltaBottomLeft;
    private int _xDeltaBottomRight;
    private int _yDeltaBottomRight;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imgMapper = findViewById(R.id.imgMapper);
        layoutTopRightMarker = findViewById(R.id.layoutTopRightMarker);
        layoutTopLeftMarker = findViewById(R.id.layoutTopLeftMarker);
        layoutBottomRightMarker = findViewById(R.id.layoutBottomRightMarker);
        layoutBottomLeftMarker = findViewById(R.id.layoutBottomLeftMarker);

        layoutTopLeftMarker.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        _xDeltaTopLeft = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                        _yDeltaTopLeft = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDeltaTopLeft;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDeltaTopLeft;
                        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        layoutTopRightMarker.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        _xDeltaTopRight = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                        _yDeltaTopRight = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDeltaTopRight;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDeltaTopRight;
                        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

        layoutBottomLeftMarker.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        _xDeltaBottomLeft = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                        _yDeltaBottomLeft = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDeltaBottomLeft;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDeltaBottomLeft;
                        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

        layoutBottomRightMarker.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        _xDeltaBottomRight = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                        _yDeltaBottomRight = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDeltaBottomRight;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDeltaBottomRight;
                        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the idea manipulate their x and y, instead of margins. when you set your layout params your mapping atomatically gets updated and thats why they are following each other. if you set x and y of the view they will still move but their layout params wont be updated.